# Show that Two Vectors Making Supplementary Angles?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

I just need a start. I am not looking for whole prove, but it'd be more appreciated if I get one.

Q. Use Theorem u . v = |u| |v| cos a and the trigonometric identity, cos (180-a) = -cos a, to conclude
that the angles formed by u and v and by -u and v are supplementary
(add to pi rad).

[a link to the Theorem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HAgqzkegBNaktoSmFkb2E5Wk0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Use $u \cdot v=|u||v|cos(a)$ 
and $(-u) \cdot v=-(u \cdot v)=-|u||v|cos(b)$

what can you say about a and b?

Comment: Well, that's the part I don't get. I can prove this theorem geometrically, but I don't know how can I prove with equation. I think for a and b, their sum should be equals to 180, i.e, a+b=180.

Comment: A vector can also be seen as a set of coordinates: $u=(u_{1},u_{2},...,u_{n})$. Then $-u=(-u_{1},-u_{2},...,-u_{n})$ since you reverse the direction of the vector. Use the algebraic definition of the dot product: $u \cdot v = u_{1}v_{1} + u_{2}v_{2} +... u_{n}v_{n} $ to show $(−u) \cdot v=−(u \cdot v)$

Comment: Yes their sum should add to 180

Comment: Yes, I know their sum should be equals to 180, but how can I show it using the theorem? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $u \cdot v = |u||v|cos(a)$ and $(-u) \cdot v = -(u \cdot v) = |u||v|cos(b) $

Rearranging gives us $cos(a) = \frac{u \cdot v}{|u||v|}$ and $cos(b) = -\frac{u \cdot v}{|u||v|}$

Then $cos(a)=-cos(b) \Rightarrow cos(b)=-cos(a) \Rightarrow cos(b)=cos(\pi -a)$

Comment: Thank you for your all efforts, but I still don't get it. I know how it works on geometrically, but I am not quite sure how it worked theoretically. Well, I don't have much of a choice cos I have to submit this question tomorrow, and in that case I don't have much of a choice but accept your answer, and copy it onto my paper sheet. Thanks again!